# The requested module './react.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am learning React but i am stuck here since a week , can't figure it out !!
please help
I am learning React but i am stuck here since a week , can't figure it out !!
please help

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Load our React component. -->


</head>
<body>
   <div id="apps">

   </div> 
   <script type="module" src="./script.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Navbar.js:

```
import React from './react.js';
//import {ReactDOM} from './react-dom.js';
export class NavBar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  }
    }
    render() { 
    return ( this.props.items.map(item =>{ <li>{item}</li>}));
    }
}
```

script.js

```
//import {React} from './react.js';
//import {ReactDOM} from './react-dom.js';
import   {NavBar}  from './navbar.js';
ReactDOM.render(
  <NavBar items={['Rohit','Rajiv']}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I am getting this error
`The requested module './react.js' does not provide an export named 'default'`

Comment: do you have a react.js file? if not, u have to change to import React from 'react'. Notice that when you import an existing file u have to start your import with a dot.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, in your provided source code there are several issues that stand out.

To take advantage of the answers provided to you here it will require some understanding of how react works, such as setting up a basic react project, and some familiarity with the react eco-system, such as node, npm and babel. Not to mention a sufficient understanding of JavaScript and the ES6 syntax.

There are many getting started guides for react available online that can get you up and running in a short amount of time.

I recommend ignoring your current progress for now and start with this guide.

[w3Schools.com React Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/react/default.asp)

Follow all the steps in this tutorial. It is explained step by step, and by the end of it you will have solid understanding of using react. Take your time, and finish this tutorial from start to finish. That is my advice, as finishing one tutorial from start to finish is better than starting 50 and not finishing them.

If you would like, leave a comment and you can get in touch with me via email with any difficulties and Ill do my best to help out.

Best of luck and hope you have fun along the way.